# Microsd card slots: shared vs dedicated - What is the difference?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, storage, hardware, internal-sd

When I look at detailed specifications of android devices sometimes it is possible to filter them by choosing if a microsd card slot is shared or is dedicated.

Unfortunately I am not able to find a resource describing what that means and what the difference is.

1. MicroSD storage will be shared between what?
2. MicroSD storage will be dedicated to what?

Internal / external storage? SIM-modules? Anything else?

And whats the pros and cons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're most likely looking at DualSIM devices. If they come with a *dedicated* SD card slot, you can use 2 SIMs *and* an external SD card. If it's a shared slot, it's either 2 SIMs *or* 1 SIM + SD card – i.e. the SD card slot is shared with the slot for the second SIM.

Comment: So I can plug in 1 SD card and at any time either a second SIM card or an SD card because there is this "shared" or hybrid slot and not 2 SIM card slots + one extra slot for SD cards, right?

Comment: Make the first SD card a SIM ("I can plug in 1 SIM card"), and that's it, yes.

Comment: Ups, of course you're right.